# Iterate over two objects and set one equal to the other in it's corresponding position

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have a set of values that, based on a given calculation, outputs a number, which is supposed to be used as a width (just a number) to make some boxes a certain width (and height). The number of boxes is the same as the number of values given. So if there are seven values, there will be seven boxes and these boxes must be the width that is being outputted from first function I wrote.

So the output value 1 from calculateBoxWidth is the width of box 1, output value two from the same fuction is the width of box 2, etc.

I'm wondering what's a simple but clean way to code this. I think in essence I just want to iterate over two objects and set one equal to the other in it's corresponding position.

This is my code so far:

```
var values = [0, 2, 4, 8, 10, 12, 14];

/*
 * Calculate the width
 */
function calculateBoxWidth(valuesArray) {
    var boxWidths = new Array();
    var maxNumber = Math.max.apply(null, valuesArray);

    for (var i = 0; i < valuesArray.length; i++) {
        var value = values[i];
        var calculatedWidth = ( (value/maxNumber) * 70 ) + 30;
        boxWidths.push(Math.round(calculatedWidth));
    }

    return boxWidths;

}

/*
 * Set the width (and height)
 */
function setBoxDimensions() {
    var theBox = document.getElementsByClassName('the-box');
    var theWidths = calculateBoxWidth(values);

    for (var i = 0; i < theBox.length; i++) {

        // ??
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < theWidths.length; j++) {
        // ??
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you asking how, given a collection of n html elements, and n widths, how do you set the 1st element to have the 1st width the 2nd element to have the 2nd width, etc. If that's what you want, I'd recommend iterating over your list of elements, and use a fallback width if, somehow, your array of widths has a different length:

```
function setBoxDimensions() {
    var theBox = document.getElementsByClassName('the-box');
    var theWidths = calculateBoxWidth(values);

    for (var i = 0; i < theBox.length; i++) {
        // use a fallback of 0 if theWidths[i] is undefined
        var widthStyle = '' + (theWidths[i] || 0) + 'px';
        theBox.item(i).style.width = widthStyle;
    }
}
```

If you want to set the height to the same value as well, then add in:

```
theBox.item(i).style.height = widthStyle;
```

inside your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function calculateBoxWidth(valuesArray) {
    var boxWidths = [];
    var maxNumber = Math.max.apply(null, valuesArray);

    for (var i = 0; i < valuesArray.length; i++) {
        var calculatedWidth = ( (valuesArray[i] / maxNumber) * 70 ) + 30;
        boxWidths.push(Math.round(calculatedWidth));
    }

    return boxWidths;

}
```

Since you're passing in the same `values` array defined above in the call to `calculateBoxWidth()`

Comment: Thanks but not sure how this solves the question, perhaps I should be clearer in the question. Will update.